# Python script to convert pcap to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, wireshark

I used the below code to convert all my pcap files that are in folders, subfolders to csv files with the given columns. The output csv file need to get the same name as its input pcap file. Code doesn't give any error. But no output. Please help me to correct if my code is wrong. python 3.6

```
import os
import csv
import subprocess
startdir= '/root/Desktop/Files/'
outdir = '/root/Desktop/Outcsv'
suffix= '.pcap'

def decode_to_file(cmd, in_file, new_suffix):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    fileName = outdir + '/' + in_file[len(startdir):-len(suffix)] + ".csv"
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fileName), exist_ok=True)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open(fileName, 'w'))
    for line_bytes in proc.stdout:
        line_str = line_bytes.decode('utf-8')
        csv_writer.writerow(line_str.strip().split(','))

for root,dirs, files, in os.walk(startdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(suffix):
            continue
        in_file=os.path.join(root,name)
        out_file = outdir + '/' + in_file[len(startdir):-len(suffix)] + ".csv"
        cmd = 'tshark -r "{}" -T fields -e frame.time_delta_displayed -e frame.len -e wlan.sa - e wlan.da _E separator=, _E header=y > "{}"'.format(in_file, out_file)
        csv_writer = csv.writer(open(out_file, 'w'))
        print (cmd)
        os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed

Comment: on Linux `os.system` need command as single string, not list.

Comment: @furas then getting a error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/Ate/pcapToCsv.py", line 22, in <module>
    out_file = outdir + '/' + in_file[len(startdir):-len(suffix)] + csv
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "module") to str

Comment: probably you need string `".csv"` instead of module name `csv` in this line

Comment: I am new to python coding, so I am not sure where I am getting wrong.

Comment: I though that you wrote this code. You use `+ csv` in two places but you need string `+ ".csv"`

Comment: @furas thanks for the reply. Would you please tell me which line/s I need to change?

Comment: use search in editor and find `+ csv`

Comment: did the change, not working ['tshark', '-r', '/./vmlinuz', '-T', 'fields', '-e', 'frame.time_delta_displayed', '-e', 'frame.len', '-e', 'wlan.sa', '-e', 'wlan.ra', '-e', 'wlan.ta', '-e', 'wlan.da', '-e', 'frame.time', '-E', 'separator=,', '-E', 'header=y', '>', '/..//vm.csv']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/AppAct/pcapToCsv.py", line 39, in <module>
    os.system(cmd)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: as I said in second comment `os.system` needs single string instead of list. So you have to convert it to string. `'tshark -r' + in_file + '...' + out_file`

Comment: or `cmd = " ".join(cmd)`

Comment: you couldn't use this code before because it has too many mistakes.

Comment: cmd = 'tshark -r "{}" -T fields -e frame.time_delta_displayed -e frame.len -e wlan.sa - e wlan.da _E separator=, _E header=y "{}"'.format(in_file, out_file)

Comment: i changed as above. no errors, but no output

Comment: you need `>` in cmd to redirect to `out_file`. It write to file but it doesn't read from file to display it. Instead of this it open file in write mode `open(out_file, 'w')` so it deletes all from file.

Comment: I added the > mark.  Your second point is not clear to me, would you be able to show where in my code I need to do the changes please. Kind request

Comment: script converts file but it doesn't display results on screen - it can display only names of converted files. If you don't see filenames then it can't find files `.pcap` in folder `'/root/Desktop/Files/'`